# Regex for remove unnecessary zeros after decimal point

Tags: regex

I need to cut some numbers:

```
21250000.022000 -> 21250000.022
20.00  -> 20
200 -> 200
20.50 -> 20.5
```

**UPDATE:**

This is what i try:
https://regex101.com/r/Sdfe5D/1
In this regex the problem is with the numnbers '200' and '20'.

Comment: Why do you think those extra digits are unnecessary?

Comment: The regex will be used on a Smarty php code, is for show prices in a pricing bar. the space is limited by 3 chars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a regex for this. Just cast your string to `double`:

```
$arr = array('21250000.022000', '20.00', '200', '20.50');

foreach ($arr as $n)
   echo (double) $n. "\n";
```

**Output:**

```
21250000.022
20
200
20.5
```

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/9ZghkY)

---

**Update:** If you're looking for a regex solution then use:

Search regex:

```
(?:(\.\d*?[1-9]+)|\.)0*$
```

replacement:

```
$1
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sdfe5D/8)

Comment: This is great solution, but i need the regex because im using Smarty in a `tpl` file. `{$p['monthly']|regex_replace:'/[.0]+$/':''}`

Comment: Perfect! @anubhava

Comment: Try that regex with, e.g. `20.0505`  Result:  `20.055`   Not so good!  Use the one by Cássio Renan instead.

Comment: Much better now!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following regular expression. I used a positive look-ahead to only select the relevant numbers: `(?=)`

```
^[^\.]+?(?=\.0*$)|^[^\.]+?\..*?(?=0*$)|^[^\.]*$
```

1. `^[^\.]+?(?=\.0*$)`: The first part looks for a number which is not a dot (`[^\.]`), followed by a dot and a random number of zeros at, which continue until the end (`$`). This matches numbers like `20.000 -> 20` or `25.0 -> 25`. It won't match any dots at the end of the line.
2. `^[^\.]+?\..*?(?=0*$)`: The second part looks is pretty similar. It looks for a number which is not a dot, followed by a dot, any characters and trailing zeros. The difference is in the brackets of the positive look-ahead: This means, it matches also characters after the dot (`\.`), but only if they are non-trailing zeros. This regex alone would match `20.0 -> 20.`. Examples for matches here are `20.04020000 -> 20.0402` or `24.120300 -> 24.1203`
3. `^[^\.]*$`: matches full numbers without any dot in it. This one is necessary for numbers like 200 or 21.

*This regular expression is based on the beginning (`^`) and the end of a string (`$`). It won't match multiple numbers in one string. When using multiple numbers in one string, line breaks need to be used to match the numbers.*

**You can test the regular expression with the following snippet:**

```js
// expected results:
// 21250000.022000 -> 21250000.022
// 20.00  -> 20
// 200 -> 200
// 20.50 -> 20.5

var regex = /^[^\.]+?(?=\.0*$)|^[^\.]+?\..*?(?=0*$)|^[^\.]*$/g;

var texts = [
  '21250000.022000',
  '20.00',
  '200',
  '20.50'
];

for(var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
  var text = texts[i];
  console.log(text, '->', text.match(regex)[0]);
}
```

Comment: What about `20.50` and `21250000.022000`? You're removing important digits.

Comment: @JonathanEdgardo It works, if the numbers are matched separately. It depends on string starts (`^`) and string ends (`$`). If you want to have multiple numbers in one string you need to adapt it to use line-endings instead of string starts and ends. Try it with one number at a time.

Comment: @AdemÖztaş Yes, you were right. I misread the question. It should now work.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I really appreciate your time in helping +rep Thank you

Comment: @JonathanEdgardo You're welcome. I just added a JavaScript example, so one can test it right in the browser.

Answer (score 3):

This regex has better performance:

```
\.0+$|(\.\d*[1-9])(0+)$
```

Replace with `$1`

#### Here's an explanation, if you're interested:

First, we deal with any whole numbers, since they're easier:

```
\.0+$
```

Then, we match the important numbers (That we want to keep) after the decimal point in a capturing group:

```
(\.\d*[1-9])
```

Finally, we match all trailling zeroes, and the end of the string (replace $ with \b if needed)

```
(0+)$
```

[See it live](https://regex101.com/r/Sdfe5D/3)

Comment: Nice regex, thanks!  If you change the first bit to `\.0*$|` (`*` instead of `+`) then it also strips the trailing decimal point if there are no zeros after it (eg. `10.`).

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to use regex for this, following would be one way:

```
preg_replace("/(\.[0-9]*[1-9]+)[0]+/", "$1", "21250000.022000");
```

However, the trailing zeroes can be removed simply by casting the string to a double:

```
(double) "21250000.022000";
```